# Backcountry Camping on Saint Pierre et Miquelon

Tags: camping, saint-pierre-and-miquelon

Is wild camping allowed on Saint Pierre et Miquelon?  There appears to be one regular campground in Saint Pierre ([streetview](https://goo.gl/maps/fobBpPxVu2qeNVWj9)), and Google Maps (but not Openstreetmap) also lists an option on Langlade [that looks more like backcountry camping](https://goo.gl/maps/JyUwJSDR2ncZoHxB8).  [SPM Tourisme](http://www.spm-tourisme.fr/1/things-to-do/nature/) notes *hiking, trekking, camping* as nature activities, but wild camping is normally prohibited in France.  Does this prohibition (or its enforcement) extend to Saint Pierre et Miquelon?

Comment: Unofficil sources in French suggest that wild camping is possible (e.g. [1](https://www.madame-oreille.com/saint-pierre-miquelon/) [2](https://www.tourismetnl.ca/region/spm_subpage_naturo/) but I have no local knowledge.